# Reading txt file to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, output

im trying to read txt file to my char array[9][9].
I tried some tips from other topics, but they didn't work.

So, I have an example file.txt like this, which I saved myself, like this:
it is 9x9

```
123------

---456---

------789
```

and so on, whitespaces here are ' ' instead of '-'.
When I'm trying to read it, and put it to my array again, it is displayed like this:

123456789.

Here's my code:

```
system("cls");
ifstream sudoku_read;
string name_read;

cout << "Put a text name: "
getline(cin, name_read);
sudoku_read.open(name_read, ios::in | ios::binary);

for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {

        sudoku_read >> tab[j][i].number;

    }
}
```

I tried noskipws also but it does not work correctly.

Comment: Use `getline` and not `>>`.

Comment: how to use getline to char array? I tried a lot and i have no idea, how it should be done

Comment: Read to an std::string, then transfer to a char array if you have to.

Comment: Im newbie at programming, could you please give an example how to tranfer string if i do sth like this:
string line;
getline(sudoku_read, line);

Answer (score 0):

```
char crs[100];
unsigned vindex = 0;
std::stringstream ss;
ss = sudoku_read.rdbuf();
std::string flstr = ss.str();
for(int i=0; i<strlen(flstr); i++){
    if(flstr[i] != ' '){
      crs[vindex++] = flstr[i];
    }
}
vindex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        tab[j][i].number = crs[vindex++] - '0'; //watch out it should be [i][j] by convention
    }
}
```

I have conventionally set crs' size to 100 since it is unspecified.

Assumptions:

- You have enough numbers in the file to fill in the matrix
- You condone using [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/) and [cstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/)

Comment: and is there another possibility, not to use vectors, I have no experience with it and I shouldn't use it now, and my university tutor forbid this for now.